# Number Ranges different year by year in SAP

Tags: range, abap, sap-basis

I need to create a number range in SAP. The number range of this kind that it has to be set must be different year by year. For ex. From 1 to 999 year  2017
From 1 to 999 year 2018. If I create new range for year 2017, when I try to create for year 2018 I got message

```
enter intervals without overlap.
```

[image]

Comment: Then do it. Whatever the actual question might be remains completely unclear.

Comment: I can't create the range for 2018, it shows me a message 'enter intervals without overlap' and I can't create it

Comment: Did you create the number range object yourself or is it a standard object - if the latter, which one?

Comment: I created the number range object, but i dont'n know how to create the intervals, to start from 1 to 999 every year.

Comment: Have you set the "To-year flag" for your number range?

Comment: And why are you inserting it with `Nr=02`? Just put there `Nr=01` and different year, the it should work.